# Python SyntaxError in defined string

Tags: python, syntax

I have to use this code:

```
local_arg = "1 : ASD|2|3|4|5, 2 : BSD|4|3|2|1, "
result_arg = {}
result_arg = {"inf" : {local_arg}}
```

SyntaxError (invalid syntax) on: `result_arg = {"infos" : {local_arg}}`
Whats wrong?

I want to use it for do this:

```
result_arg["inf"][number]
```

I have tried using:

```
result_arg = {}
result_arg = {"inf" : {1 : ASD|2|3|4|5, 2 : BSD|4|3|2|1,}}
```

And that works, but my map will be created automaticly, so using that is not a solution.

Comment: A dictionary must have a key *and* a value

Comment: @TidB: But in Python 2.7 and up you can define a *set* like that. `{value1, value2, value3}` is a set, not a dictionary. Presumably the OP is using an older version of Python.

Comment: Is `local_arg` always a string? Then you'll need to *parse* it into key-value pairs.

Comment: Sombody can make a example, please? (i don't understand english to good)

Comment: the example that you claimed is working cannot work, it's a `SyntaxError` because it lacks quoting.

Comment: ch3ka what is "lacks quoting"? i don't understand too many english, i use google translate..

Comment: Do not edit your question; the answers will not make sense if you remove the code that you are using.

Comment: The answers will not resolve the probem.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split local_arg with `,` then split the string with `len>1` with `:` (for avoid `" "`) :

```
>>> local_arg.split(',')
['1 : ASD|2|3|4|5', ' 2 : BSD|4|3|2|1', ' ']
```

so you can do this:

```
>>> s=[j.split(':') for j in local_arg.split(',') if len(j)>1]
>>> s
[['1 ', ' ASD|2|3|4|5'], [' 2 ', ' BSD|4|3|2|1']]
>>> {'inf':{i:j for i,j in s }}
{'inf': {'1 ': ' ASD|2|3|4|5', ' 2 ': ' BSD|4|3|2|1'}}
```

Comment: I have try but i get syntax error on: result_arg = {'inf':{i:j for i,j in s }}

Comment: I dont get a detailed error msg, i just get "ErrorSyntax: Invalid string - strings"..., do you have skype?, i really need help.

Comment: the code works fine fore me ? i think you have a mistake in your typing ? i nned to see your code that be ran !

Comment: i just can say you dont need `result_arg = {}` but i cant see any error !

Comment: Do you have an skype id or facebook?, there are any option alternative to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code at the end the dictionay `result_arg` will look like this,

```
{'inf': {'1 : ASD|2|3|4|5, 2 : BSD|4|3|2|1, '}}
```

here `result_arg['inf']` is a `set`. Not a dictionary with key value pairs. So you are getting error. There might be some other issue in your code, It should give a `TypeError` not `SyntaxError`.

From the string, you can approach like this,

```
local_arg = "1 : ASD|2|3|4|5, 2 : BSD|4|3|2|1, "
d = [itm.split(':') for itm in local_arg.strip().split(',') if itm]
c = dict((int(itm[0]), itm[1]) for itm in d)
result_arg = {}
result_arg = {"inf" : c}
```

Now you can print,

```
print result_arg["inf"][1]
```

will give you output like this,

```
ASD|2|3|4|5
```

Comment: I got SyntaxError at: c = dict((int(itm[0]), itm[1]) for itm in d)

Comment: I dont know what is your string like, and it's not mentioned in your question also. while asking question try to give sample input that works for you.

Comment: give the message with the `SyntaxError`

Comment: Thank you for help, anyway i just get only this msg: SyntaxError - invalid syntax

Comment: No one can help you with this information. Paste your full code show where are you getting this `SyntaxError`. If you get error after copy pasting my code then there might be indentation issue.